# PHP mySQL - How to get data from row after using IN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i make a query to get access to `answer_choice` inside while loop.

In this case i have two tables:

```
af_questions 
    question_id

af_answers
    answer_from // user id
    answer_to  // question id 
    answer_choice // user choice
```

PHP:

```
$questions = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM af_questions WHERE question_id IN (SELECT answer_to FROM af_answers WHERE answer_from = :user_id)');
    $questions->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $questions->execute();

   while ($row = $questions->fetch()) {
        $question_id = $row['question_id'];
   }
```

Comment: what's exactly the problem?

Comment: Not sure what exactly your problem is, but in mysql, each derived table should have it's own name. In your case you should have `SELECT ... WHERE question_id IN (SELECT ... ) AS t`.

Comment: ah, I think I got it. Make a join instead of a 'IN (subselect)'

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, I think you want to restructure your SQL to use `JOIN` instead?

Comment: I'm open-minded newbie in sql world and yeah i was looking for better option which is join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer the question you asked; the question doesn't make sense to me.

It looks to me like what you are really after is the result from a query like this:

```
  SELECT q.question.id
       , a.answer_choice
    FROM af_questions q
    JOIN af_answers a
      ON a.answer_to = q.question_id
   WHERE a.answer_from = :user_id
   ORDER BY q.question_id
```

Then in the fetch loop, you'll have access to both `question_id` and `answer_choice`.

---

I'm pretty sure this doesn't answer the question you asked. But if we can backup from that, I'm pretty sure this approach will help you achieve your objectives.

Comment: My point was to get only questions which has been answered by specific user. Your query is perfect solution. Thanks.